# How can I retrieve multiple contacts in Ionic using the Cordova contacts plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am currently using the `navigator.contacts.pickContact()` function, which only returns a single contact. Instead of getting a single contact, I would like to get multiple contacts at the same time. I have tried using the `navigator.contacts.find()` function, but it returns the whole contact list. How can I get multiple contacts using this plugin?

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried? And what is your use case? Are you for example trying to get all contacts with a specific lastname? And why is the `find()` function not working for you?

Comment: Actually I am trying to create new user in my app, as far as single user creation is concerned the pickContact method is fine, suppose if I need to create more than one user the pickContact does not allow to select more than one contact. find() returns entire list so, I have to write custom component to allow user to select multiple contact of their choice.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done directly with the plugin the way you want. You have to do a `navigator.contacts.find(['*'], (contacts) => {})` retrieve all contacts and make a custom component to select only those that you want.
The plugin directly don't allow to show a multi-picker.